# set up custom domain name in Jitpack

Tags: github, jitpack

I'm trying to publish a library using [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/). By default the groupId is set to `com.github.username.repo` but I would like it to be `com.mydomain.libs` instead. [The official docs](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/blob/master/README.md#custom-domain-name) say that for that I need to

> Add a DNS TXT record that maps git.yourcompany.com to https://github.com/yourcompany

What does this actually mean? Should I do this somewhere on github or on my `mydomain.com` website?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out, that this is something to be done on the `mydomain.com` website, so there is no way currently to set up a custom domain name on Jitpack if you don't own that domain name.